# alternative for wilcox.test in R

Tags: r

I'm trying a significance test using `wilcox.test` in R. I want to basically test if a value `x` is significantly within/outside a distribution `d`.

I'm doing the following:

```
d = c(90,99,60,80,80,90,90,54,65,100,90,90,90,90,90)
wilcox.test(60,d)



    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  60 and d
W = 4.5, p-value = 0.5347
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(60, d) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

and basically the p-value is the same for a big range of numbers i test.

I've tried `wilcox_test()` from the `coin` package, but i can't get it to work testing a value against a distribution.

Is there an alternative to this test that does the same and knows how to deal with ties?

Comment: by the way, I can't reproduce your example -- when I use `x=60` with your `d`, I get `W=1.5`, `p=0.2018` instead of the results you quote above.

Comment: @Ben Bolker because he is using the `wilcox_test()` from the `coin` package, not `wilcox.test()` from the `stats` package.

Comment: really?? that's not what they show in their code chunk.  You may notice that I did implement `coin::wilcox_test` in my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How worried are you about the non-exact results?  I would guess that the approximation is reasonable for a data set this size.  (I did manage to get `coin::wilcox_test` working, and the results are not hugely different ...)

```
d <- c(90,99,60,80,80,90,90,54,65,100,90,90,90,90,90)
pfun <- function(x) {
    suppressWarnings(w <- wilcox.test(x,d)$p.value)
    return(w)
}
testvec <- 30:120
p1 <- sapply(testvec,pfun)
library("coin")
pfun2 <- function(x) {
    dd <- data.frame(y=c(x,d),f=factor(c(1,rep(2,length(d)))))
    return(pvalue(wilcox_test(y~f,data=dd)))
}
p2 <- sapply(testvec,pfun2)
library("exactRankTests")
pfun3 <- function(x) {wilcox.exact(x,d)$p.value}
p3 <- sapply(testvec,pfun3)
```

Picture:

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
matplot(testvec,cbind(p1,p2,p3),type="s",
      xlab="value",ylab="p value of wilcoxon test",lty=1,
        ylim=c(0,1),col=c(1,2,4))
legend("topright",c("stats::wilcox.test","coin::wilcox_test",
                    "exactRankTests::wilcox.exact"),
       lty=1,col=c(1,2,4))
```

[image]

(`exactRankTests` added by request, but given that it's not maintained any more and recommends the `coin` package, I'm not sure how reliable it is.  You're on your own for figuring out what the differences among these procedures are and which would be best to use ...)

The results make sense here -- the problem is just that your power is low.  If your value is *completely outside the range of the data*, for n=15, that will be a probability of something like 2*(1/16)=0.125 [i.e. probability of your sample ending up as the first or the last element in a permutation], which is not quite the same as the minimum value here (`wilcox.test`: p=0.105, `wilcox_test`: p=0.08), but that might be an approximation issue, or I might have some detail wrong.  Nevertheless, it's in the right ballpark.

Comment: Ben, could you also add the `wilcox.exact` procedure from the `exactRankTests` package to this "benchmark"? I did this and obtained slightly different results (this package throws a warning indicating that it is not maintained anymore - however the last update is only 2 months old)

Comment: (that's `pfun3 <- function(x) {wilcox.exact(x,d)$p.value}` -- I would do it myself but it makes no sense to write a new answer just for this..). Bottom line is: this test gives also a non-significant p-value, however with yet another value that is higher (p=0.3125).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, the point is that my data size varies a lot. what I give here is just an example. The question is: would the distribution size variation affect the p-value calculation a lot? I kind of needs p-values to distinguish between the categories (presented by number x).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand the question.  Your power will certainly vary with the sizes of both data sets, but that's more or less inevitable (there *may* be a more powerful way to achieve the same general goal, possibly at the expense of more restrictive assumptions, but that would definitely be a CrossValidated question).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
wilcox.test(60,d, exact=FALSE)
```